# Passing variable into CURL command using bash scripting (with double quotes in variables value)

Tags: bash, variables, curl

I am having trouble with creating and then using a variable that contains double quotes in the value and have really struggled to find any other posts with such an example, some with special characters but none specifically looking at using double quotes.

I am looking to create a variable in a bash script that will allow me to perform the following CURL command with the "text" value as the variable

```
curl -v -o POST \
-u "apikey:-------------------------------------" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "text":"Hello World",
  "features": {
  "sentiment": {},
  "categories": {},
  "concepts": {},
  "keywords": {},
  "emotion": {} 
  }
}' \
"https://gateway-wdc.watsonplatform.net/natural-language- 
understanding/api/v1/analyze?version=2018-03-19" 
$SHELL
```

I have tried the below but, although the echo looks like it was passing the right value, the CURL response is a 400 error - invalid response.

```
VAR1='"Hello World"'

echo "VAR1=${VAR1}"
echo 

curl -v -o POST \
-u "apikey:-------------------------------------" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
     "text":${VAR1},
     "features": {
     "sentiment": {},
     "categories": {},
     "concepts": {},
     "keywords": {},
     "emotion": {}  
    }
}' \
"https://gateway-wdc.watsonplatform.net/natural-language- 
understanding/api/v1/analyze?version=2018-03-19"
$SHELL
```

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Don't generate JSON data by hand. It'll fail if `$VAR1` contains quotes or backslashes. Use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to do it safely and robustly.

Answer (score 2):

(There is a duplicate for this, but I can never find it.)

Use a tool like `jq` to build the JSON.

```
data=$(jq --argjson x "$VAR1" '
  {
    text: $x,
    features: {},
    sentiment: {},
    categories: {},
    concepts: {},
    keywords: {},
    emotion: {}  
  }'
)
curl ... -d "$data" ...
```